# Why the code keeps throwing an exception "Cannot create a file" when that file already exists?

Tags: c#, winforms

I make first a check if the file is not existing, but it keeps getting inside the throw exception.

Maybe I should use try catch in that case and not `if File.Exists` ?
Or some other logic to handle a case the user tries to repeat the same action.

I want that the user will not be able to repeat that action over again. The user should not handle it, but the code should.

The exception occurs on the line:

```
Directory.Move(currentLightningFolderPath, fName);
```

> System.IO.IOException: 'Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

Code:

```
int currentLightningEndFrame = currentLightningStartFrame + framesCaptured - 1;
double currentLightningStartTime = (currentLightningStartFrame - 1) / videoCapture.Get(VideoCaptureProperties.Fps) + videoStartTimeInSeconds;
double currentLightningEndTime = (currentLightningEndFrame - 1) / videoCapture.Get(VideoCaptureProperties.Fps) + videoStartTimeInSeconds;
string frameRange = $"[{currentLightningStartFrame:D4}-{currentLightningEndFrame:D4}]";
string lightningFolderName = $"Lightning{folderNameCounter:D3}_{frameRange}";

string fName = Path.Combine(lightningsFolderPath, lightningFolderName);

if (!File.Exists(fName))
{
    Directory.Move(currentLightningFolderPath, fName);
    currentLightningFolderPath = null;
    framesCaptured = 0; // Reset the counter
    folderNameCounter++;

    detectedLightnings.Add((currentLightningStartFrame, currentLightningEndFrame));

    logger.Log("Lightning Detected: " + lightningFolderName, Color.Yellow); // Empty line
}
```

In this case the file name the content in the variable fName is:

```
D:\\New folder (9)\\Lightning000_[9004-9007]
```

and the content in the variable `currentLightningFolderPath` is:

```
D:\\New folder (9)\\Lightning9004
```

The variables are correct and logic, because the variable `fName` and present the name of the lightning so in my logic it's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're checking if a *file* exists:

```
if (!File.Exists(fName))
```

Then trying to create a *directory*:

```
Directory.Move(currentLightningFolderPath, fName);
```

These are two different things.  According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists):

> To check if a directory exists, see Directory.Exists.

For example:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(fName))
```